# Normal Random Variables and convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

I'm stuck with a problem of probability.
Suppose $\{N_n,n \geq 0\}$ is a sequence of normal random variables. Show $N_n \Rightarrow N_0$ iff 
$$E(N_n) \to E(N_0)$$
and 
$$Var(N_n) \to Var(N_0).$$
I'm done when I suppose the convergence of the expected value and the variance, but i'm not able to make a proof when I suppose $N_n \Rightarrow N_0$.

Comment: Can you clarify your comment?  Since the normal distribution is entirely characterized by its mean and variance, and convergence in distribution is a pretty weak convergence, it almost seems self-evident that this is true.  What did you mean by "I'm not able to make a proof..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weak convergence is equivalent to convergence of characteristic functions. Take absolute value in characteristic functions to see that the variances converge. Then it becomes obvious that the means also converge.

Comment: I see... this is the Continuity theorem?

Comment: $e^{itx}$ is a bounded continuous function so the characteristic functions converge.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you elaborate on why this works? $\phi'_{N_n}$ may not necessarily converge to $\phi'_{N_0}$. We need a uniform continuity condition on the derivatives. How to get that from finite variance?